# Calling Dbus method without expecting a reply

Tags: python, dbus

I have a dbus client written in python to call the exposed dbus methods. The code is as follows

```
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
service = bus.get_object(PANEL_BUS_NAME, PANEL_BUS_OBJECT)
__panelInterface = dbus.Interface(service, PANEL_BUS_INTERFACE)
__panelInterface.SetBTConnected()
```

The problem is that when the method is called first time, it takes a while for the exposed method to get executed. My understanding is that the dbus expects a reply from the method's process but times out. However, what I fail to understand is that the method gets executed immediately if called again. In other words, the block occurs only the first time. Can somebody recommend me the remedy for this behavior and help me understand it??

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of what you are doing? Is the code above all there is?

Also, what Python binding are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to debug this with a D-Bus analysis tool like [Bustle](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Bustle/) or [`dbus-monitor`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html). They will show you when the messages and replies are sent, whether any errors are returned, and where the time is spent.